# Firefox automation with selenium how to loop and repeat an action

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I would like to code how Firefox opens a website and clicks a button.

I would like Firefox to wait 30 mins and then close everything. I would like to loop this action.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox

YOUR_PAGE_URL = 'http://www.websyndic.com/wv3/?qs=OTcxNzAw'
NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH = '/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/a'

browser = Firefox()
browser.get(YOUR_PAGE_URL)

button = browser.find_element_by_xpath(NEXT_BUTTON_XPATH)
button.click()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: perhaps a `for` loop, or maybe a `while` loop? I could also see a `time.sleep` might do the trick?

Answer (score 0):

As per your code is concerned, I don't see any issue out there. Now if you want to loop and repeat the actions after any pre-defined interval there are a few options available as follows :

### Looping Options :

- You can use the [**`ScheduledExecutorService`** **Interface**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) from **`java.util.concurrent`**
- Use a **`Continous Integration`** tool like [**`Jenkins`**](https://jenkins.io/) to support building, deploying and automating any project.
- You can use the functionalities extended by **`Windows Scheduler`** to start your **`Test Execution`**.
- Configure a **`Cron Job`** to execute your **`Test Suite`** at pre-defined intervals.